# Different operations in the ring of integers

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is it possible that the integers still form a ring with the usual addition operation, but a different multiplication operation? If so, describe all such rings. How about with the usual multiplication operation, but different addition operation?

Comment: How about $x*y=-xy$ for a new multiplication?

Comment: @AnginaSeng idea works more generally: If you fix an invertible element $u \in A$ and define another multiplication $x * y = uxy$, you will get another ring, but your new ring is isomorphic with the first one (being $x \mapsto ux$ the isomorphism)

Comment: “If so, describe all such rings.” Note that you are not assigning us homework or giving us instructions. Please phrase your questions as questions, indicating context and what you have managed to do.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the usual addition, and some multiplication $\odot$ that makes $(\mathbb{Z},+,\odot)$ a ring, then for any $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ you must have
$$0\odot a = (0+0)\odot a = 0\odot a + 0\odot a$$
which proves $0\odot a= 0$. Then for any $a,b\gt 0$ we have
$$\begin{align*}
a\odot b &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^a 1\right)\odot \left(\sum_{i=1}^b 1\right)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^a\sum_{i=1}^b (1\odot 1)\\
&= ab(1\odot 1).
\end{align*}$$
And using the fact that in any ring $(-a)\odot b = a\odot(-b) = -(a\odot b)$, we see that the value of $\odot$ is completely determined by $1\odot 1$.

If we let $1\odot 1=u$, then this gives the multiplication $a\odot b = (ab)u$ (with usual multiplication on the right hand side).

This gives a ring (possibly without unity):

- $(a\odot b)\odot c) = (abu)\odot c = (abc)u^2$, and $a\odot (b\odot c) = a\odot (bcu) = a(bcu)u = (abc)u^2$, giving associativity;
- $(a+b)\odot c = (a+b)cu = acu+bcu = (a\odot c) + (b\odot c)$, giving distributivity (note that $\odot$ is commutative, so this suffices).

For this to be a ring with unity, we would need an element $x$ such that for all $a$, $a = a\odot x = axu$. For $a\neq 0$ this can only happen if $xu=1$, so $x=u=1$ or $x=u=-1$. If $u=1$ we get the usual multiplication; if $u=-1$ we get the one proposed by Angina Seng in the comments.

If $u=0$, you get the trivial multiplication.

These are the only possible multiplications if you want the usual addition and for the resulting structure to be a ring (possibly without unity).

---

Still working on the “same multiplication, different addition” part; but note that if $(\mathbb{Z},\oplus,\cdot)$ is a ring, with $\cdot$ the usual multiplication, then
since the neutral element for $\oplus$ is absorbing in any ring, and the only absorbing element for $\mathbb{Z}$ is $0$, it follows that $0$ remains the $\oplus$-neutral element.

Answer (score 0):

Every abelian group can be turned into a ring with trivial multiplication $xy = 0$ (where $0$ is additive identity). Angina Seng in the comments also suggests another multiplication operation. You are basically trying to talk about all the rings with underlying set with cardinality $|\mathbb{N}|$. There will be a lot.